# Grpc Unity Could not load signature of Google.Protobuf

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, protocol-buffers, grpc

I just downloaded the latest version of unity package grpc but I have encountered the following issue:

```
Error: Could not load signature of Google.Protobuf.ByteString:get_Span due to: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. assembly:System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 type:<unknown type> member:(null) signature:<none> Unloading broken assembly Assets/Plugins/Google.Protobuf/lib/net45/Google.Protobuf.dll, this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime
```

Unity Version: 2019.3.0f1

Does anyone have a solution for this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:unityscript]

Comment: First of all download https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Protobuf/  3.10.0 version ,then change to .net 4.6 in unity settings rebuild and try